# Как хранить остатки по товарам в разрезах товара и даты в Django?

Tags: python, django, account

Я новичок в django. Есть задача написать приложение для движения остатков на складе. Приложение должно уметь получать данные в разрезе товара или товаров в разрезе даты или интервала дат, или на конкретную дату.

**Теоретически я понимаю структуру модели:**

1. модель Product (товар)
2. Модель Document (Документ Приход/Расход)
3. Модель DocumentRow (Табличная часть документа)
4. Модель Transactions (промежуточная таблица для хранения остатков, здесь должны записываться остатки на каждый месяц).

Для пункта 4 нужно записывать остатки в разрезе месяца и товара. Для актуальности данных в этой таблице мне нужно при записи DocumentRow на конкретную дату пересчитать все остатки после этой даты.

Пример:

1. 01.10.2018 Приход 10
2. 15.10.2018 Приход 20
3. 12.12.2018 Расход 10

Записи в таблице Transactions (Месяц, НачальныйОстаток, КонечныйОстаток)

1. 01.10.2018 0  10
2. 01.10.2018 10 30
3. 01.12.2018 30 20

***Я не знаю можно ли это реализовать на django, по факту мне нужен аналог оборотно-сальдовой ведомости, мне нужно Ваше мнение или свежие идеи***

Comment: Парни помогите советом. Буду очень рад